# How to use ng-bind in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.masterVer = "";
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <td>
    <input ng-model="masterVer" />
  </td>
  <tbody id="update_check" style="text-align:center">
    <tr ng-model="updateproducts" ng-repeat="item in selectResult track by $index | orderBy : 'siteCode'">
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="updateVer_{{$index}}" ng-bind="masterVer" value="{{item.ver}}">
      </td>
```

I would like to deliver the value of `ng-model` by giving the `ng- bind="masterVer"` property to the  object which will be generated in repetitive statement of ng-repeat. I do not know how to bind in repetitive statement. Please give me help.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You don't use `ng-model` on `<tr>` or `ng-bind` on `<input>`.  Please explain in more detail exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is using `[]` object notation for variable property names

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in selectResult | orderBy : 'siteCode'  track by $index">
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item[masterVer]">
      </td>
```

Note that there is no point setting `value` when using `ng-model`